# Unable to do refactoring on my Swift file in Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, xcode9

I am using **Xcode 9** and I am trying to do **Refactoring** on my `Swift` based file but every time I am getting below error:

> Refactoring engine ranges didn't match initial ranges

[image]

Why isn't it matching the initial range?

Comment: this is still a thing in Xcode 10.3

Comment: Still going strong in 13.1 !

Comment: 13.3! It's the bug that keeps on giving. (I tried to rename; was told this was an illegal re-declaration, undid the rename, deleted the other file, and got the error. Building did nothing. After restarting, I opened the file... with the new name already in place.)

Comment: Apple should literally outsource creating the IDE to Jetbrains!

Comment: It happens in Xcode 15 too! Just rebuilding the project fixes it

Answer (score 34):

Build your project (<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>) and it will fix the error. After doing it, I could rename my file successfully.

Comment: This works for me with XCode 13.3 (13E113).

Comment: Restarting Xcode didn't work for me, but this did. Xcode 13.3 (13E113)

Comment: Works in Xcode 15 as well. It happened when I moved a file to a different folder and rebuilding the project made it work

Answer (score 30):

Workaround: Restart Xcode.

This has not been resolved yet as of January 2018 (Xcode 9.2).

Comment: In Xcode 9.2, close the project and open it again (don't have to restart Xcode). Worked for me

Comment: I think clearing out derived data will make the indexing working once again and you shouldn't need to restart Xcode... Altought paradox is that restarting Xcode is faster :D

Answer (score 7):

**Update** For some reason, it's not happening for me anymore. I noticed also whenever I don't let indexing finishes before trying to start doing a refactor or tap on refactor many times, still see the error, but not permanent anymore.

I asked an engineer at WWDC 2018 about this issue. This issue was happening for me in only one project in my workspace. Other projects in the same workspace works fine. At the moment, there's no solution to this issue. If you want to help Apple to fix this, you can close your Xcode and run following command in terminal:

```
SOURCEKIT_SERVICE_LOG=3 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode 2>&1 | tee /tmp/sk-log.txt
```

And then try to reproduce the issue and send them the log file (`/tmp/sk-log.txt`) so they can narrow it down and hopefully fix it in future Xcode versions.

**Notice** This is project related issue and won't be fixed with OS updates, Xcode updates, or any number of restarting applications, at least the one that I'm having.

Answer (score 7):

I have Xcode's project created using Xcode8 long time ago. For some reason I have to upgrade to Xcode9 (9.4.1 exactly). Then I experienced that error only on that old project, not the new one created using Xcode9.

So i think that error related to project issue. So I decided to compare the settings between old and new one. There are some differences, and after several tries, by changing `Optimization Level for Debug` solved refactor issue.

1. In project editor, select your `Target`, `Build Settings`
2. Set `Optimization Level (Debug) = No optimization [-Onone]`
3. Delete `DerivedData` folder related to your project in `/Users/YourMacUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
4. Clean project <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>.
5. Build project <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: I am using Xcode 12.4 and this solved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue in Xcode 10.3. 
Refactoring didn't work when I right clicked → refactor → rename on the class name in the class definition. However it did work when I did the same somewhere in code where I use that class.

Comment: Have you made a feedback on http://feedbackassistant.apple.com ?

Answer (score 3):

Product -> Clean Build Folder -> Quit Xcode -> Reopen Project -> Build

Answer (score 2):

I update to Xcode 10 and finally refactoring now it works again after a year without refactoring

Comment: Just got one in Xcode 10. :-) But I believe it is a limitation in Xcode to do refactoring without actually building it.
For my case. I rebuilt it then that error is gone when I tried to refactor.

Comment: @Paul same was for me

Comment: @Paul Add another instance in Xcode 10 - all well after clean/rebuild.

Comment: @Paul And another on Xcode 13.2. It seems the "ranges" refer to the build targets (e.g. iPhone 13 Pro)

Answer (score 2):

I am on Mac M1 and using Xcode Version 12.5 beta 3. 
I was facing the same issue when trying to rename ViewController. 
Before renaming it, I moved it to a new group, and my code was in a running state. Not sure if that was the reason for the issue. 
But I restarted the Xcode and the issue was resolved for me.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this on a Mac M1, using Xcode Version 14.1 (14B47b).

This helped:
Clean project: shift-command-k.
Build project: command-b.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the exact same issue. It turned out that I had my build configuration set to `Release` mode. Changing it to `Debug`, cleaning build folder and recompiling fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

## Remove `DerivedData`

This worked for me for this error and other kind of refactoring errors.

1. Close Xcode
2. Remove DerivedData:

`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 14.2: New project and tried to refactor the name of the ViewController and got the rename error pop up. Saved the the project and did a build. Refactoring the file name worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

In case none of the above works (usually does for me too, except for this one time when it didn't), this is what worked for me:

1. I remove reference of the file (but still keep the actual file).
   [Remove reference window option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPG87.png)
2. I open the folder where I have the file I previously removed and I drag and drop the file in the same place I needed it to be. Make sure Copy items if needed in ***unselected***.
   [Drag-and-drop window option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqeth.png)
3. Clean build folder and Build.
4. Wait for indexing to finish.
5. Refactor.

Note: I'm using Xcode 14.3

Answer (score 0):

None of the below worked for me. But I could do it.
This is my solution.

My case was like:

```
variable = [self functionName];
```

and "functionName" failed to refactor > rename. What I did is took this function call in brackets like this:

```
variable = ([self functionName]);
```

After that I could rename this function.